# Global state in a (wix) react-native-navigation app?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-navigation

I'm putting together an app with [`react-native-navigation`](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation).

I need to have some global state available but I can't figure out how to implement it. Usually I'd have a stateful top-level component and pass methods that call `this.setState` to lower components as props—but the two `Navigation` methods provided by `react-native-navigation`, `startTabBasedApp` and `startSingleScreenApp`, cause any parent component to dismount. Dismounted components can't have state changed according to the error logs, so I'm at a loss.

What am I missing? How can I share state between my components (screens) with this solution?

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [Redux](https://github.com/reactjs/redux). There is an example here- https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/tree/v1.1.81/old-example-redux

It is unmaintained but the principle should be the same. My app works fine with it even on version 1.1.81.

Comment: there is a new [example](https://github.com/JuneDomingo/movieapp) as you can see in the [docs](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/usage)